# Pandas : Replace NaNs with mean of 'n' nearest non-empty values in column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe.

```
     A      B
0   NaN     12
1   NaN    NaN
2    24    NaN
3   NaN    NaN
4   NaN     13
5   NaN     11
6   NaN     13
7    18    NaN
8    19    NaN
9    17    NaN
```

In column 'A', the missing values need to replaced with the mean of say 3 nearest non empty values in a sequence if they exist.
 For example the NaN at **index 5** has 18 as its nearest non empty value and after 18, the next two values are also non empty. Therefore the NaN at index 5 is replaced with (18+19+17)/3.
The NaN at **index 4** has 24 as its nearest non empty value but the two values prior to 24 are non empty. Therefore the NaN at index 4 is not replaced with any value.
Similarly it needs to be done with the rest of the columns. Does anyone know a vectorized way of doing this? 
Thanks!

Comment: what would be index 0, A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need combine rolling with `mean` with another rolling from back, then use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) for replace nearest `NaN`s by `mean`s with forward filling for last groups of `NaN`s and backfilling for first groups of NaNs for helper DataFrame `c`, which is used for replace missing values of original DataFrame:

```
a = df.rolling(3).mean()
b = df.iloc[::-1].rolling(3).mean()

c = a.fillna(b).fillna(df).interpolate(method='nearest').ffill().bfill()
print (c)
      A          B
0  24.0  12.000000
1  24.0  12.000000
2  24.0  12.000000
3  24.0  12.333333
4  24.0  12.333333
5  18.0  11.000000
6  18.0  12.333333
7  18.0  12.333333
8  19.0  12.333333
9  18.0  12.333333

df = df.fillna(c)
print (df)
      A          B
0  24.0  12.000000
1  24.0  12.000000
2  24.0  12.000000
3  24.0  12.333333
4  24.0  13.000000
5  18.0  11.000000
6  18.0  13.000000
7  18.0  12.333333
8  19.0  12.333333
9  17.0  12.333333
```